# Is there a function to stop mobile android browser from automatically reloading after locking phone?

Tags: javascript, android, sapui5, reload

I have developed a UI5/Javascript Webapp. It is working functionally correct.

**The problem is the following**: I open the app online to load all ressources. Than I lock the android phone and after 10 minutes i want to access the app (OFFLINE!) again. The browser (chrome and firefox) want to reload the page but with no internet connection it is not possible.

Is there any option/function/setting to stop the android browser from reloading the webpage?

Or is there any browser that can do that?

Comment: It's a browser issue alright. Chrome have got rid of the flag that let's you control this, so instead you could use Firefox and then switch off auto refresh.
Type "about:config" in the address bar.
Click the "I accept the risk" button.
Type "accessibility.blockautorefresh" in the search box.
Double-click on the first item that appears to change the value to "true".
Restart Firefox.

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer! Do you have any idea why chrome is doing so?

Comment: Can't remember when they added this, but originally they did let you switch it off, then they got rid of this, on desktop, you can still switch it off at site level by going to chrome://discards. Pain in the neck when testing.

Comment: unfortunately, the setting "accessibility.blockautorefresh" is not available at my android phone

Comment: Did a small bit of reading, have you tested in Firefox, I think it is actually turned off by default on Android, so you might be good to go.

Comment: Thank you! i will test this!